# Flask with a webserver breaks all sessions?

Tags: python, session, flask, lighttpd

For example, this code:

```
from flask import session

@app.route('/is_logged_in/')
def is_logged_in():
  return 'user' in session
```

It runs fine for me when running Flask's development server, but it throws a `500` error with *any* webserver setup (FastCGI, uWSGI, etc.) on any server (Apache, nginx, Lighttpd).

Anybody know why?

---

My actual code is on GitHub, if it matters.

It works flawlessly when running with Flask's internal server, but I can't get any session variables to work with a production webserver: https://github.com/Blender3D/Webminal/blob/master/server.py

Comment: Please provide a stack trace for the error. You can do that by setting `app.config['DEBUG'] = True` and/or looking in the server's error log.

Comment: Can you see if request hit inside is_logged_in() when running on a web server? Most likely your server rules are blocking the path.

Comment: @sjn: Every URL decorator I use works, except the ones that mention `session`. I have `app.debug = True` in my config in my `fcgi` and `wsgi` files, but still no backtrace.

Comment: The reason I think it's a problem with sessions is because my `login` function never logs in. I have `flash()` functions setup at various stages, yet I can never successfully save a session variable (my login information is accepted, but the session never begins).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I finally tried [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/), thinking it would help with my problems (it's written in Python, after all).

Lo and behold, a readable traceback:

```
RuntimeError: the session is unavailable because no secret key was set.
Set the secret_key on the application to something unique and secret.
```

Looks like I just forgot to add a secret key to sign sessions with:

```
app.secret_key = 'why would I tell you my secret key?'
```

Comment: daaaa... you just did tell me your secret ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your return value must be one of several types: a `basestring` (`string` or `unicode`), a `tuple` (representing arguments passed to the constructor of a `Response` object), a `Response` object itself, or -- failing those -- a WSGI-callable function.

You are returning a `bool`. Flask is assuming that since it's not a `basestring`, `tuple` or  `Response` object, it must be a WSGI-callable. Subsequently, when processing the response it attempts to call() your `bool` return value which results in an exception. Flask catches the resulting TypeError. When Flask is in debug mode, it'll pass this back up to Werkzeug's simple webserver, which will invoke the built-in debugger. When Flask is in production mode, however, it'll merely bubble up an internal server error -- e.g., code 500 -- with no further information.

So, to fix your problem, make sure you do this instead:

`return str('user' in session)`

Comment: This is just an oversimplification of my problem, sorry for the misunderstanding. In my code, I render my `index` page if my user is not logged in (`return redirect(url_for('index'))`) and the actual page if the user *is* logged in (same logic).

Comment: Look at my edited question for the code I'm actually using. It isn't much different.

Answer (score 0):

Though, it doesn't really answer your question, I would rewrite it this way:

```
from flask import redirect, session, url_for

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'foo'

@app.route('/is_logged_in/')
def is_logged_in():
    user = session.get('user', None)
    if user:
        return user
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Comment: `'user' in session` checks whether `user` is a key in the dictionary, which is a one-line version of your logic. If you can help, my actual code has been edited into my question.